# Trying to upload an image using Firebase storage and Firestore Database - encountering a map error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am pretty new to React -  I am attempting to add an image to my firestore database while it gets stored in firebase storage. The photos will also render on the screen after they have been uploaded successfully. I am working with nested collections. I don't understand why setPhotos is not being recogonized.
I am getting this error once I go my path :

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
_callee3$

src/components/AddNewPhotos.js:74
  71 | .collection('dates')
  72 | .doc("day_1")
  73 | .get();
> 74 | setPhotos(
     | ^  75 |   photoCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
  76 |     return doc.data();
  77 |   })
```

This is what my code looks like at the moment.

```js
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { storageRef , usersCollection} from '../tools/firebase.js'
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import firebaseConfig from '../tools/firebase';
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthConnect";




function AddNewPhotos() {
    const {currentUser, userDetails} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = React.useState(null);
  const [photos, setPhotos] = React.useState([]);

  const onFileChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const storageRef = firebaseConfig.storage().ref();
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
    await fileRef.put(file);
    setFileUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await usersCollection
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection('locations')
    .doc('VBfRdZZVgSEOoNkythmW')
    .collection('dates')
    .doc("day_1")
    .set({
      travelphotos: fileUrl,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPhotos = async () => {
      const photoCollection = await 
      usersCollection
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .collection('locations')
      .doc('VBfRdZZVgSEOoNkythmW')
      .collection('dates')
      .doc("day_1")
      .get();
      setPhotos(
        photoCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
          return doc.data();
        })
      );
    };
    fetchPhotos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {photos.map((photo) => {
          return (
            <li >
              <img width="100" height="100" src={photo.travelphotos} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default AddNewPhotos;
```

I have nested collections. I would like for the travelphotos to be an array with photos that are strings.]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore structure and show where the photos array is?

Comment: hello! added a picture to show the structure of my firestore. the photo gets added to my database but not as an array only as a string. Do I need to change my code in order for the images to get added into the array ? @Dharmaraj

Comment: I've updated my answer. Yes you are setting it as a string and not as an array. Using `arrayUnion` will add new items to the array.

Comment: thank you, that started the array in my database. However, when I go in and add another image I don't see it get appended?

Comment: Is it the same code that adds new image to that array? Also make sure you the file url is updated first and then you add it to db. If an item already exists in that array, it won't be added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `get()` method on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which will fetch that specific document's [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) and not a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) containing multiple documents so you don't cannot use a map on that.

Are the photos stored in an array in that document? If yes then you would have to set that array in your state like:

```js
setPhotos(photoCollection.data().travel_photos);
```

When adding new photos to document, you are setting it as a string. Instead use `arrayUnion` to push the URL to that array:

```js
await usersCollection
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection('locations')
    .doc('VBfRdZZVgSEOoNkythmW')
    .collection('dates')
    .doc("day_1")
    .set({
      travelphotos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(fileUrl),
    });
```